# Cocoa: Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am trying to build my project but it is not getting build.

I am getting the following error:

```
Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

I have cleaned my project but still is issue is persisting.

Xcode Details:

[image]

**EDIT Solution tried**

I went to

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

and deleted everything inside the folder then went back to the Xcode and tried to build the solution. Getting the same error back

```
Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Close Xcode, clean `DerivedData` and try again.

Comment: How to clean derive data? Please provide steps. Many thanks sir

Comment: No, go and search.

Comment: @Droppy Sir, I went to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and deleted everything inside the folder then went back to the `Xcode` and tried to build the solution. Getting the same error back `Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

clean your project and see whether it help or not

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>K</kbd>

or

> Product > Clean

Or check this link it may helps you: http://codica.pl/2015/12/25/taming-swift-compiler-bugs/

Answer (score 3):

For Mac OS Sierra, this work for me:

> cd  /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

then

> xattr -dr com.apple.FinderInfo *

and then **rebuild your project**..

and fix the error!

Answer (score 2):

All of sudden, It happens to my Mac app project today in Xcode 7.3.1.

What I did :
Clean >Clean build folder > Quit Xcode >Open Finder then go to

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

then deleated everything inside >Open Xcode >Build >Run

I think this is happening when something is wrong adding a file into Xcode.
I have not encountered since readding myApp.help file without the option 'Destination: Copy items if needed'.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error messages and find out which files are affected. Delete these files (remove references) and then add them again to your project's target. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

```
clear "Derived Data" from files.
Xcode >> Preferences >> Locations >> click on arrow icon(opened "DerivedData" folder)
remove/delete all files from "DerivedData" folder.

clean project(cmd + swift + k)
```